# Convert query from mysql to postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a query in mysql that determines employees in a certain age range.

```
SELECT p.last_name, p.first_name, p.bdate
FROM personaltab p
WHERE YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(p.bdate)
- (DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(p.bdate, '%m%d')) >= 21  AND 
YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(p.bdate)
- (DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(p.bdate, '%m%d')) <= 30 AND 
p.perstatus='ACTIVE'
```

How will I do it in postgres that will not include people where their birthdays did not occur yet on current date

Comment: Have you actually tried the SQL query in Postgres? Why did it fail?

Comment: Technically you should be able to run any MySQL query on Postgresql without any issues.

Comment: @The Odd Developer, we get 0.1000 from `(1/3)`  in MySQL, but they say the same expression returns 0 in PG.

Comment: @blabla_bingo - The reason is the PG integer division truncates fractional digits. To get fractional digits, cast to numeric before dividing. More info - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: @KarelFrajták yes. and the YEAR function does not work in Postgres.

Comment: `1/3 = 0.1000` really?

Comment: The function AGE() does magic in calculating ages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to manipulate the dates. The [age](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date-functions/postgresql-age/) function accomplishes this directly. It actually returns result in years, months, days. You can then extract the years. So something like: (See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/PlFTHkWz)).

```
select extract(year from age(<column>)) 
  from <table>;
```

Or for your full query:

```
select p.last_name, p.first_name, p.bdate
  from personaltab p
 where p.perstatus = 'ACTIVE'
   and extract(year from age(p.bdate)) between 21 and 30;
```

NOTE: NOT tested - no data supplied.